# How to click a button on a redirected page?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code on my initial page

```
<html ..
<script> 

<input type= "button" onClick="location.href('http:www.google.com')">
```

How can I click the OK button on the google page ones redirected using ONLY javascript. Is it possible ?

Comment: got it thatnks . why thankfully ?

Comment: No you cannot, it's a security issue if you can which is why you can't. also missing // in http:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once the user has been redirected away from your website, you cannot access the DOM any longer using JavaScript.

You could achieve something like this using a Chrome Plugin or some such, but thankfully this is not possible using native JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to click OK button on Google page, but if it's to launch search, why you don't try to redirect with search parameter like :https://www.google.ca/#q=google+search+javascript